# How to pass Dynamic value via param in symfony 1.4 routing.yml

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4, paramarray

I want to display the external url like this:

```
www.abc.com/username
```

This page requires `group_id`, `ticket_id`, but i dont want to display these variables in external urls.

My `routing.yml`:

```
my_profile:
  url:   /:username
  param: { module: profile, action: index, grp_id: GRRf3eedfb7-842d-4cbd-a17f-141334cd1b4d, ticket: UAe25d7784-7b9f-499a-8e53-57f5aee91d95, display: true }
```

`indexSuccess.php`

```
echo url_for('@my_profile?module=profile&action=index&username='.$username.'&grp_id='.$groupID.'&ticket='.$ticket)
```

Note that in the `routing.yml` `params` has static `grp_id` and `ticket`. It outputs Nicely.

However, I want want to make it dynamic. `grp_id` and `ticket` should come dynamic values and they should not be visible in the URL.

Comment: Where do you want the dynamic values to come from?  `grp_id` & `ticket` values in your database?  Do you want them hidden just because they'd make a ugly URL, or because the user shouldn't know them?  If you want them hidden just so you have nice urls you could past them in as post params.

Comment: Hum, you can't. If they are dynamic, you must set them in the url. You might use session to store them without showing them in the url.

Comment: @therefromhere:  Yeah, i want them hidden just because i want Nicde urls. How to pass as  "post params"

Comment: via a form, look at the doctrine documentation for forms

Comment: Sir, in my profile page, i have one or more postings.Title, description, comments.